ORDER BY CASE in sort pageable java spring
In the same way as this question: Similar solution I would like to know if it is possible to pass ORDER BY CASE WHEN exID = 2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END from angular to java spring or the variable to order by the exID.
Initially, in my case, I have params = params.append(‘sort’, matSort.active + ‘,’ + matSort.direction) where matSort.active = exID,field1,field2,field3 and matSort.direction = asc. How do I get the backend to sort by a variable that is not present in the DTO entity I return and when the repository method uses a nativequery?
I tried using JpaSort.unsafe, but I got a syntax error because somehow the query uses a reference table
SQL result from console
TableEx1 te
ORDER BY
    te.CASE WHEN exID.id = 2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 
END,
field1 asc,
field2 asc,
field3 asc

And this is how it is until now:
angular service function
listSomething(page: MatPaginator, matSort: MatSort) {
    let params: HttParams = FormsUtil.generateParamsForPaginationWithSorting(page, matSort);        
    return this.http.get<Page<ClassExample>>(${this.endpoint}/list-something, {params}); 
}  

util.ts
static generateParamsForPaginationWithSorting(page: MatPaginator, matSort: MatSort): HttpParams {
    let params: HttpParams = this.generateParamsForPage(page);

    if (matSort != null && matSort.active != null) {
        const attribute = ['exID.id', 'exID.IDType', 'EXID.IDType'].find(field => matSort.active.includes(field));

        if (attribute) {
            params = params.append('orderByExID', attribute);
        }

        params = params.append('sort', matSort.active + ',' + matSort.direction);
    }
    return params;
}

java spring function
// CONTROLLER:
@GetMapping(“/list-something”) public Page<ClassExample> listOrder(Pageable page, String orderByExID) {
    return service.searchListOfSomething(page, orderByExID);
}

// SERVICE:
public Page<ClassExample> searchListOfSomething(Pageable page, String orderByExID) {
    page = createSortForExIDOrder(orderByExID, page);
    return repository.searchListOfSomething(page);
}

private Pageable createSortForExIDOrder(String orderByExID, Pageable page) {
    if (orderByExID != null) {
        Sort sort = JpaSort.unsafe(Sort.Direction.ASC, "CASE WHEN " + orderByExID + " = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END");
        sort = sort.and(page.getSort());
        return PageRequest.of(page.getPageNumber(), page.getPageSize(), sort);
    }
    return page;
}

Note: I know you can put it directly into nativeQuery, but I want to know other ways of making it work

I think this should be possible with JPA Criteria Queries
https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries
@Override
public Page<ClassExample> searchListOfSomething(Pageable pageable) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<ClassExample> query = cb.createQuery(ClassExample.class);
    Root<ClassExample> root = query.from(ClassExample.class);

    // Apply sorting dynamically using Criteria API
    List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
    pageable.getSort().forEach(sort -> {
        if ("customExIdSort".equals(sort.getProperty())) {
            // Create the CASE WHEN statement dynamically
            Expression<Integer> caseExpression = cb.selectCase()
                .when(cb.equal(root.get("exID").get("id"), 2), 0)
                .otherwise(1);

            if (sort.isAscending()) {
                orders.add(cb.asc(caseExpression));
            } else {
                orders.add(cb.desc(caseExpression));
            }
        } else {
            // Default sorting
            if (sort.isAscending()) {
                orders.add(cb.asc(root.get(sort.getProperty())));
            } else {
                orders.add(cb.desc(root.get(sort.getProperty())));
            }
        }
    });

    query.orderBy(orders);
    TypedQuery<ClassExample> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);

    // Pagination logic
    typedQuery.setFirstResult((int) pageable.getOffset());
    typedQuery.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());

    // Execute and return the result
    List<ClassExample> resultList = typedQuery.getResultList();
    return new PageImpl<>(resultList, pageable, getTotalCount(cb));
}

private long getTotalCount(CriteriaBuilder cb) {
    // Implement logic to return the total count for pagination
    // For simplicity, this part can be optimized
    return 100; // Placeholder
}

I'm not an expert in criteria. But maybe this helps you anyway :)
